# Serializing and Deserializing

Tags: java

I have two questions.

1) if you have a program that has a series of primitives that change under certain conditions but you need to save the value of the primitives even after the program is closed,would you use Serialization and Deserialization?

2) If so,how do you do it/what does the code look like.
    package Lib;

```
public class App {
     static vars obj = new vars();
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        runLogic(obj);
    }
    private static void runLogic(final vars obj){
        int book;
        String person;
        int date;
        String dateToday;

        int i = (Integer)0;
        String a;
        String one = null;
        int i2 = (Integer)0;
        String b;
        String two = null;
        int i3 = (Integer)0;
        String c;
        String three = null;
        int i4 = (Integer)0;
        String d;
        String four = null;
        int i5 = (Integer)0;

        for (;;) {

            System.out.println("\n\nMAIN MENU\n"+
                    "Press:\n" + 
                    "1 and then 'enter' for checkout,\n"+
                    "2 and then 'enter' for check in,\n" +
                    "3 and then 'enter' to look at books checked out,\n"+
                    "4 and then 'enter' to look at books overdue");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int main = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (main) {
            //checkout
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter the book number");
                Scanner booknum = new Scanner(System.in);
                book = booknum.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the person's name");
                Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
                person = name.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter the number of weeks the book can be borrowed for");
                Scanner weeks = new Scanner(System.in);
                date = weeks.nextInt();
                int millis = date * 604800000;
                System.out.println("Enter today's date");
                Scanner theDate = new Scanner(System.in);
                dateToday = theDate.nextLine();

                Timer time = new Timer();
                if (book == 1) {

                    i = 1;

                    a = "1";

                    one = a +" is checked out by " + person + "(due by "+ date + " weeks)" + "-checked out on " + dateToday;


                    time.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                        public void run(){
                         obj.set(0.5);

                        }
                    },millis);

                }

                if (book == 2) {
                    i2 = 2;

                    b = "2";

                    two = b +" is checked out by " + person + "(due by "+ date + " weeks)" + "-checked out on " + dateToday;
                    time.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                        public void run(){
                         obj.set2(0.5);

                        }
                    },millis);



                if (book == 3) {
                    i3 = 3;

                    c = "3";

                    three = c +" is checked out by " + person + "(due by "+ date + " weeks)" + "-checked out on " + dateToday;
                    time.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                        public void run(){
                         obj.set3(0.5);

                        }
                    },millis);
                }
                if (book == 4) {
                    i4 = 4;

                    d = "4";

                    four = d +" is checked out by " + person + "(due by "+ date + " weeks)" + "-checked out on " + dateToday;
                    time.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                        public void run(){
                         obj.set4(0.5);

                        }
                    },millis);
                }
                if (book == 5) {
                    i5 = 5;

                    e = "5";

                    five = e +" is checked out by " + person + "(due by "+ date + " weeks)" + "-checked out on " + dateToday;
                    time.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                        public void run(){
                         obj.set5(0.5);

                        }
                    },millis);
                }


                break;
                //check in
            case 2: 

                System.out.println("Enter the book number");
                Scanner s6 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int byeBook = s6.nextInt();
                if (byeBook == 1) {
                    i = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 2) {
                    i2 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set2(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 3) {
                    i3 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set3(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 4) {
                    i4 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set4(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 5) {
                    i5 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set5(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 6) {
                    i6 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set6(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 7) {
                    i7 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set7(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 8) {
                    i8 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set8(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 9) {
                    i9 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set9(0);
                }
                if (byeBook == 10) {
                    i10 = (Integer) 0;
                    obj.set10(0);
                }

                break;
                //checked out books
            case 3:
                System.out.println("here are the books checked out");
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println(one);
                } else {

                }
                if (i2 == 2) {
                    System.out.println(two);
                } else {

                }
                if (i3 == 3) {
                    System.out.println(three);
                } else {

                }
                if (i4 == 4) {
                    System.out.println(four);
                } else {

                }
                if (i5 == 5) {
                    System.out.println(five);
                } else {

                }

                break;
                //overdue books
            case 4:
                double done = obj.get();
                double dtwo = obj.get2();
                double dthree = obj.get3();
                double d4 = obj.get4();
                double d5 = obj.get5();

                if (done == 0.5){
                    System.out.println("Book 1 is overdue.To find out who has the book checked out,look at the list of checked out books.");
                }
                if (dtwo == 0.5){
                    System.out.println("Book 2 is overdue.To find out who has the book checked out,look at the list of checked out books.");
                }
                if (dthree == 0.5){
                    System.out.println("Book 3 is overdue.To find out who has the book checked out,look at the list of checked out books.");
                }
                if (d4 == 0.5){
                    System.out.println("Book 4 is overdue.To find out who has the book checked out,look at the list of checked out books.");
                }
                if (d5 == 0.5){
                    System.out.println("Book 5 is overdue.To find out who has the book checked out,look at the list of checked out books.");
                }


            }
        }
    }
    //manage overdue functionality
    static class vars{

         double od;
         double od2;
         double od3;
         double od4;
         double od5;


            void set(double val){
                od = val;
            }
            double get(){
                return od;
            }
            void set2(double val2){
                od2 = val2;
            }
            double get2(){
                return od2;
            }
            void set3(double val3){
                od3 = val3;
            }
            double get3(){
                return od3;
            }
            void set4(double val4){
                od4 = val4;
            }
            double get4(){
                return od4;
            }
            void set5(double val5){
                od5 = val5;
            }
            double get5(){
                return od5;
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Define what you mean by *primitives*

Comment: 1. Yes, if the primitives are fields in an Object instance. 2. Depends on what format I'm serializing to. There's Java's Serializable and Externalizable, but there is also writing to and reading from XML and/or JSON.

Comment: Save it to a file/DB. If you're referring to Android you can use [*SharedPreferences*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what would be the easiest way to serialize all the primitives,strings,etc. in this java program?  http://codetidy.com/4790/

Comment: @noobProgrammer Click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25008518/edit) and add the code here.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The code is too long

Comment: @noobProgrammer Sounds like you should try and rewrite it into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ok I've edited the post with the code in it

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is used for short-term persistence in Java. It's ok to persist a few objects using serialization, however for a large number of objects and primitives, using a database is preferred because it ensures its ACID compliant. Where as if you choose to serialize- once your code base grows, class changes make your serialized data unreadable, and having non-java based code use that information via I/O is impossible.

Comment: Using a database itself doesn't guarantee ACID. There are many databases and many ways to handle them. Even JPA, if set incorrectly, doesn't guarantee anything.

Also, serialization of objects and database insertion may be the same things.

Comment: yes, there are a couple of databases that aren't ACID complaint, like MongoDB and a few other flavors of non-relational databases. But if you look at this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems. Literally all relational databases are ACID complaint.

Comment: Also, Serialization and an ORM / database are different things, although there is some overlap. A serialized object represents all of the information needed to "thaw" a persisted object and repopulate its data. An ORM and database persist data to a database. A class can have fields of information that are not stored in the database by the ORM, for example computed field. serialization and an ORM are solving different problems.

Comment: An ORM handles the mapping of pieces of information to database columns and the retrieval and instantiation of objects, in addition to providing niceties such as searching and lazy loading.

Use an ORM when you want to persist data to a database for situations where you're dealing with large amounts of data or need reporting, searching / querying, warehousing or other things that databases are good at. Use serialization when you want to save a representation of your data structure(s) to disc.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically [two degrees](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/deepcopy_and_shallowcopy.php) of serialization:

1. Shallow copy
2. Deep copy

Shallow copy copies all the "primitive" variables, but doesn't serialize other objects as well. Deep copy serializes all.

Serialization is very general term. You can do it any way you want. It means taking your object and saving it in ANY permanent storage, in ANY form.

Common ways of serialization:

1. Convert to JSON. (Google GSON library is excellent at this.)
2. Convert to XML (Java has some libraries included).
3. Insert into database. JPA makes your life easier here.
4. Store in a key=value file (VERY SIMPLE if you only need to make shallow copy).

Do not be afraid to have a look at Google Gson or JPA (though JPA is probably too complex to understand for you at the moment). These are just few, there are definitely many more ways to do serialization.

Comment: how would I do the 4th one(Store in a key = value file)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit of terminology confusion going on here.  Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization):

> serialization is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.

Almost everything computers do, other than display things for users to look at, is some form of serialization.  Reading and writing to files or databases, creating and parsing JSON, XML, CSVs, and other structured data formats, all count as serialization.  Effectively, the key requirement to call something serialization is that it's reversible - as long as (relevant) data isn't lost in the writing process, your program is serializing whatever it's working with.

Now all of that is not to be confused with [Java Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html), which is a specific way to serialize data, specially designed for Java objects and data structures.  There are pros and cons to using Java Serialization (personally, I'd say far more cons, but that's neither here nor there) but it is merely one of many ways you can "*save the value of the primitives even after the program is closed*".  Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you may simply want to write your data to a text file, and read it in again.  Many times, anything beyond that is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends.

   - Serialization is a binary format, the saved values are therefore not easily editable by other tools (so no opening the file in an editor and changing values). If that were required, java.util.Properties or [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/index.html) would be a better fit.
   - Serialization is a Java-only format, programs written in other programming languages will have trouble reading it. If that is required, I'd use JAXB (or JSON, if the target language is JavaScript).
   - Serialization is somewhat brittle when the format changes (i.e. values are removed), because it is tighly coupled to the classes in your source code. If you need to load files written by a past version of your program, this will limit the changes you can easily do to the file format. If that is a problem, JAXB would be a better fit.
   - Deserializing untrusted data may be a security vulnerability.
   - Serialization is easy use. If you are willing to live with the above restrictions, it is probably the easiest choice.
2. This is already [explained in the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, and based on your latest edit I think I do, change `vars` -

```
static class vars implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
```

Then a demo using ByteArrayInputStream and OutputStream,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  vars v = new vars();
  v.set(1.0);
  v.set2(2.0);
  v.set3(3.0);
  v.set4(4.0);
  v.set5(5.0);
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
        baos);
    oos.writeObject(v);
    oos.close();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        baos.toByteArray());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
        bais);
    vars dev = (vars) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(dev.get5());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

`vars` should really be `Vars` by Java naming standards, but the above outputs the expected

```
5.0
```

Comment: The part I don't really understand is when you run a java program,the flow is top to bottom right? So say the object is saved and the program is closed.When it starts up again it won't jump to the part where the object is read back(deserialized) so how exactly does this work?

Comment: @noobProgrammer No. Java is not "top" to "bottom". The object value is serialized, not it's execution context.

Comment: Oh sorry about that.How would serializing the values of certain primitives(ints, doubles) work then?

Comment: @noobProgrammer The value is written and read as bytes to some stream. See the code above.

Comment: Alright one last question.If you have an Integer in the beginning(int i = 5;) of the program but it changes later in the program(i = 0;).Afterwards it is serialized.When the program is restarted will the Integer get set back to 5 since int i = 5; is the first line of code.

Comment: Only if you deserialize that value to I. Or an object instance that has a unique field I.